# Cannot Import Pyscopg2 with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, installation, psycopg2

I am currently using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.  I have a script that once worked well with ArcGIS Desktop and utilized ArcPy and psycopg2 libraries.

I understand now it is required to use propy.bat file path when trying to use stand alone scripts like below.

```
c:\Progra~1\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\scripts\propy.bat my_script.py
```

When I execute my script this way I get 'No module named 'psycopg2''.

However I am confident psycopg2 is installed. I can verify this by starting python in terminal and running import psycopg2 without error.

[image]

Is there something special that needs to be done to execute a script using both libraries with ArcGIS Pro 3?

Comment: "starting python in terminal," which terminal exactly?  Do you have multiple Python installations on the machine because ArcGIS Pro 3.0 is bundled with Python 3.9.11, and the screenshot shows 3.7.9.

Answer (score 1):

[Psycopg](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) is a PostgreSQL database adapter for Python.

In ArcGIS Pro, you can to download/install PostgreSQL client libraries from the *Products Menu* as described here : https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012190.

**Note** : Make sure after the install to remove `import psycopg2` before re-executing your script.

Comment: Thx but then I get  NameError: name 'psycopg2' is not defined.. When psycopg2.connect() is called? @M92_

Answer (score 0):

Using the propy.bat file will ensure that the script is run using the currently-set conda environment, as defined in the ArcGIS Pro settings.

So make sure the desired environment is set and has the psycopg2 package installed. To check the settings, open ArcGIS Pro and go to the backstage/settings menu -> Python -> Installed Packages. If you don't see it listed you can use the Add Packages option to install it (you may need to clone the default environment first).

[image: View of ArcGIS Pro settings panel showing the python packages for the currently selected environment.]